# Symfony2 radio-button group from Entity

Tags: symfony, radio-button, twig, grouping

I wondered if there is a way to define the name of radio fields in twig for grouping. currently its this:

```
<input type="radio" 
       value="6" 
       required="required"
       name="root_companybundle_company[products]"
       id="root_companybundle_company_products_6">
```

Where the name gets generated automatically.
The best would be to define the name in the FormType element. like:

```
namespace Root\CompanyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('products', 'entity', array(
                'class'    => 'CompanyBundle:Product',
                'label'    => 'Produkts',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,

                'groupBy' => 'groupName'
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Root\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'root_companybundle_company';
    }
}
```

`groupName` would be a field(string) in my Product Entity. So it could look like this:

```
<input type="radio" 
       value="6" 
       required="required"
       name="root_companybundle_company_mygroupName[products]"
       id="root_companybundle_company_mygroupName_products_6">
```

So I could easily get my radiobutton with  `{{ form_widget( new_form.products ) }}` instead of making a new radio group every time.

I looked everywhere but didn't find anything. Is there a way?

Comment: Please share the code of your form type. Why do you mean by *grouping*?

Comment: I want to change the name attribute for my radio buttons so i have groups (example: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

My Product Entity has a groupName field that i want to use to group all entries with the same value.

Also i edited the whole FormType in.

Comment: In the linked example, groups are used to select two different choices. You want to separate the options by grouping them but only select one element from the list?